# Simple inequalities

Tags: inequality

Given that $0<a<-b$ what may we deduce about $(a+b)/a$?

This implies that $(a+b)/a < 0$ which I can write as $-|a+b|/|a| < 0$ so that $|a+b|/|a|>0$. Is this all I can conclude?

My prof says to me that the quantity $|(a+b)/a| < 1$ but I haven't been able to see this yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0<a$ you know that $|a|=a$ and since $a<-b \implies a+b<0$ you know that $|a+b|=-a-b$. So you have that $$1>\left|\frac{a+b}{a}\right|\iff |a|>|a+b| \iff a>-a-b \iff 2a>-b$$
which is not necessarily implied by the given inequality $0<a<-b$. So, no, I do not see how your lecturer reaches this conclusion.

Comment: Ok, many thanks, it is what I thought. Kind of unrelated to the question, but in this website of hypergeometric identies, http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/ShowAll.html, it relates the hypergeometric 2_F_1(a,b,c,z) = U(a,b,a+b-c+1, 1-z). Would you know what U stands for here? The reason I wanted |1-z|<1 (and that the prof incorrectly concluded) was so that I could make a transformation to a converging hypergeometric.

Comment: I did not see any $U$ in this page you sent (and there was much in it...) . But I do not think I know, sorry.

Comment: Ah sorry, it was under 'Generic general cases', the very last one in that list.

Comment: It is another hypergeometric function. Click on it and then look for Hypergeometric U. I do not know more, sorry, I cannot help you with this

Comment: Ok no problem! thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think your prof might be wrong.

Assume the quantity $\Big|\frac{a + b}{a} \Big| < 1$ is correct for $0<a<-b$. This implies

$|a+b| < |a|$.

Take now $a = 1/3$ and $b = -1$. We have

$|a + b| = 2/3$

which is certainly bigger than $1/3 = |a|$.